# Visual Code: Emmet html auto comment stopped working

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, emmet

I have just discovered my visual studio emmet html auto comment feature ( |c ) has stopped working. Emmet Docs still intact, and the feature still working in sublime text 3. Tried to re-install the IDE but the problem persisted.

Comment: First, try [disabling all extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_disable-an-extension) to make sure one of these is not causing this. If you still see the problem after disabling extensions, please file an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a versioning specific issue. I updated to v1.16.1 and the problem was fixed.